# Dimensions error, in seq2seq model (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [512,64], [5739,64]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In seq2seq model, encoder last should be initial state of input.

but i got dimension error.

```
inp=Input(shape=(train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1]))
inp=tf.reshape(inp,[train_X.shape[0],train_X.shape[1]])
print(inp.shape)
encoder = Embedding(input_dim=8,output_dim=64, mask_zero=True,embeddings_initializer='uniform')(inp)
encoder = LSTM(64, input_shape=train_X.shape, return_sequences=True, unroll=True)(encoder)
encoder_last = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1,:])(encoder)
print(encoder_last.shape)
encoder=tf.reshape(encoder,[-1,5739])
print(encoder)
```

RESULT

```
(5739, 8)
(5739, 64)
Tensor("Reshape_42:0", shape=(512, 5739), dtype=float32)
```

and decoder

```
decoder = Embedding(8,64,mask_zero=True)(encoder)
print(decoder.shape)
initial_state=[encoder_last, encoder_last]
print(initial_state)
```

the shape of decoder and initial_state belows

```
(512, 5739, 64)
[<tf.Tensor 'lambda_22/strided_slice:0' shape=(5739, 64) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_22/strided_slice:0' shape=(5739, 64) dtype=float32>]
```

and i connected decoder and initial_state to LSTM layer.

```
decoder = LSTM(64, input_shape= encoder_last.shape, return_sequences=True, unroll=True)(decoder, initial_state)
```

it said that

```
  ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 5739 for 'lstm_93/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [512,64], [5739,64].
```

i know dimensions have to be equal, but i can't understand what's mean of value error said. also i wonder how can i connect decoder and initial_state with LSTM layer.

Comment: What is the input of your model: sequence of integers representing words,  since you are using an embedding layer? If that's the case then why does the training data have 3 dimensions, i.e. you have used `train_X.shape[2]`?

Comment: i change original input in 2 dimensional but still got same problem:(

Comment: Edit your question and add the changes you have done and the new error you get.

Comment: i edited it but error is same:(

Comment: The samples axis should not be in the input shape, i.e. instead use `shape=(train_X.shape[1],)`.

Comment: thanks! it's works:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [official Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html), there is a thorough tutorial on seq2seq model.

You can easily pass **encoder-state** for initializing decoder with the following code:

```
# encoder
x = Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, latent_dim)(encoder_inputs)
x, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(x)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
x = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim)(decoder_inputs)
x = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)(x, initial_state=encoder_states)
```

As you can see there is no need to use the `Lambda` layer. Just set the `return_state` flag to **True** and pass the state to the decoder constructor (`initial_state`).

Comment: thanks! i pass the state initial_state and it works!